# F# mutable values are not mutable

Tags: struct, f#, mutable

I have the following struct, which should allow me to create, then modify the time and value properties, which will change the private mutable values x.Time_ and x.Value_.

```
type TimeDataPoint = 
    struct
        val mutable private Time_: DateTime
        val mutable private Value_: double

        new (time: DateTime, value: double) = 
            {
                Time_ = time
                Value_ = value
            }

        member public x.Time
            with get() = x.Time_
            and set(time: DateTime) = x.Time_ <- time

        member public x.Value
            with get() = x.Value_
            and set(value: double) = x.Value_ <- value

    end
```

However, when I try to use one of the setters in later code:

```
let tdp = TimeDataPoint(DateTime.Now, 0.0)
tdp.Time <- DateTime.Now
```

I get an error:

`Invalid mutation of a constant expression. Consider copying the expression to a mutable local, e.g. 'let mutable x=...'`

Which doesn't make sense to me because the variables are already mutable, and the struct compiles. What am I missing?

EDIT

Ok, I simplified my example because I thought it didn't matter, but I see now that it does. I actually have a LinkedList of TimeDataPoints, and I'm trying to mutate the contents of some of the nodes, so I can't declare it locally as suggested. Here is my code:

```
let myList = LinkedList<TimeDataPoint>()
myList.AddFirst(TimeDataPoint(DateTime.Now, 0.0))
myList.First.Value.Value <- 1.0
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Works perfectly well for me, as long as I define `tdp` as `let mutable tdp = TimeDataPoint()`. Can you post more context?

Comment: Your best option is not to go down this route.  The .NET struct design guidelines suggest you would be well advised to avoid mutable value types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx  You are asking to walk into a world of confusion by making mutable structs: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/

Comment: Makes sense. I changed my struct to a regular class. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to also mark your `tdp` as mutable. Stripped down code is below, and outputs:

```
Ticks is 0
Ticks is 636028131920527873
```

as expected.

```
module Mutation
open System
type TimeDataPoint = 
    struct
        val mutable private Time_: DateTime
        new (time: DateTime) = 
            {
                Time_ = time
            }
        member public x.Time
            with get() = x.Time_
            and set(time: DateTime) = x.Time_ <- time
    end

let usingTdp() = 
    let mutable tdp = TimeDataPoint()
    printfn "Ticks is %i" tdp.Time.Ticks
    tdp.Time <- DateTime.Now
    printfn "Ticks is %i" tdp.Time.Ticks
```

EDIT after question update: As mentioned in the comments, all will work well if you do away with the thing being a `struct`, for example:

```
type TimeDataPoint = 
    val mutable private _v: int
    new (v: int) = 
        {
            _v = v
        }
    member public this.Value
        with get() = this._v
        and set(v: int) = this._v <- v

let myList = LinkedList<TimeDataPoint>()
myList.AddFirst(TimeDataPoint(1)) |> ignore
myList.First.Value.Value <- 1
```

If working with F#, you might also consider re-thinking whether mutation is really your only choice - I doubt it is.

PS: If you decide to stick with a mutating object, consider using the auto properties syntax, which allows you to shorten your class definition to:

```
type TimeDataPoint(v, d) = 
    member val Value: int = v with get, set
    member val Time: DateTime = d with get, set
```

Comment: Can you post a complete repro of the issue?

Comment: The variable that `TimeDataPoint` is stored in only needs to be mutable when `TimeDataPoint` is a struct. If it was a class, the variable would hold a reference to an instance of the class, and the reference doesn't need to change when a property of the class is modified. For a struct there is no reference, the data is stored right there in the variable, so modifying a struct means modifying the variable, and that's why the variable itself needs to be mutable.